# Can I use Office 365 business with Dropbox Pro?

Tags: dropbox, office-365

I was used to use my Office 365 home account with Dropbox (Pro version).

I recently upgraded to the business version of Office 365 but I didn't find any ways to use it together with a Dropbox Pro account.

It seems Business version of Office 365 can only be integrated with Business version of Dropbox, not free nor pro.

Am I right ?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: No, since I switched from Linux to Mac which has a proper Office support

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot use Office 365 with Dropbox Pro. I have a suggestion for you: You can download Dropbox desktop sync version and install onto your PC. After installation of Dropbox desktop sync you'll see the folder under "My Computer" on left-hand side. Create folder on it called "office". Then create your Word, Excel, Powerpoint, etc. files and save in that folder. Dropbox syncs files automatically and you can see your files anytime, anywhere.

Comment: Forgot to say that I am a Linux user. One of the good advantages of Office 365 is to use it directly through the browser. Sadly, your proposal can't work with online versions of Office.

Comment: yes you are right this proposal for only windows users